# MCSM season 2 episodes and season pass 'unavailable'

Tags: ps4, minecraft-story-mode

I’ve just reinstalled the second season of Minecraft Story Mode, yet the two episodes I didn't install last time (episodes 4 and 5) both said "coming soon", despite having been out for a year or two. I thought buying the Season Pass would help, but it said that it was unavailable, giving the error message `WC-40636-6`.

Note: both episodes 2 and 3 also behaved like this, but were fixed after I reinstalled them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've dealt with this problem before. It's a bit too late to tell you how to fix it now, though, (I was actually never able to fix it) since the game shut down. If you made this around July or later, then just to let you know, both games shut down, so there is absolutely no way to get any of these episodes. Hopefully, this answers your question.